# How to change a Frame class's size?

Tags: python, tkinter

If I make a frame like this:

```
class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
```

How can I change it's size? Because this doesn't work:

```
class MainMenu(tk.Frame(self, width='100', height='100')):
```

And neither does `self.geometry('100x100')`. I tried finding a Frame's equivalent of `geometry()`, but found nothing. Apparently the only way to change frame's size is when you initialize it, and since the above code doesn't work, I have no idea how to do this.

I want the frame to be equal to around 90% width and height of the main `Tk()` window and anchored to the center, and also never change its size.

Comment: Use `class MainMenu(tk.Frame):` and put a call to `super().__init__(width='100', height='100')` in as the first line of its `def __init__(self):` method. This will call the subclass' baseclass' `__init__()` method and pass the argument to it.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't change its size. Tkinter is really good at making it just the right size to fit its children. Does the frame have anything inside it? Why do you want to force it to be some other size?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Because I'm using multiple frames which are in the same place and I'm focusing the one which is currently used by the user. But some of my frames require more space than the others and they would be seen when they're not supposed to be seen.

Comment: Sumerechny: FYI, you can change the size of a `Frame` (or subclass) instance after it's created by calling the universal widget `config()` method. i.e. `the_main_menu.config(width='100', height='100')`.

Comment: So why not have the smaller frame grow to fill the same space as the larger frames? Please create a [mcve] - there are probably better ways to solve then problem then by forcing a frame to a specific size in pixels.

Comment: @martineau: that typically only works if the frame has nothing in it. If it has children managed by `pack` or `grid`, the frame will ignore the `width` and `height` and instead size itself to fit its children.

Comment: @Bryan: Good point, however from what I understand resizing based on child widgets can be disabled by calling `the_main_menu.grid_propgate(0)` or `the_main_menu.pack_propgate(0)`.